# How to get Git version number - *just* the version number

Tags: regex, git

The question sounds simple but doing something like

```
git --version
```

will return string like

```
git version 1.9.4
```

while I only need the 1.9.4 part. We had a simple regex that expected "git version" followed by some digits and dots but we've had a report that the pattern matching doesn't work for some of our users - possibly because the format can be different by some other Git build? I don't know but **what's the bullet-proof way to get just the version number**? Is there a Git command that could do it? Is there a tested, 100% working regex for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the below in the language you're using

1. Split on `" "`
2. Take the element at the index 2
3. Else, use the regex if absolutely necessary - `/\S+$/`

`/\S+$/` means capture everything *except* space character at the *end* of the string. It can't be more bullet-proof, I suppose.

Comment: Point three is probably the answer. Points 1 and 2 are "dangerous" as they might not work in some cases (it appears). Still, it would be best if Git could report its version number alone but there seems to be no such command / switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

`git --version | awk 'print {$3}'`

Answer (score 0):

By command:

`git --version | cut -f3 -d" "`

By regex:

`/\s(.*)$/U`